# How to check if a string does not contain a certain word?

Tags: php

I want to check if a string does not contain two words I've got so far:

```
if (strstr($Description1,'word1') or strstr($Description1,'word2') ){ 
do Action 1
} else 
Action 2
```

The problem is it does check for the words however I want to do action 1 if it doesn't contain the 2 words. At the minute it does action 1 if it does contain the 2 words.

Any help welcome

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You said it, you want to make the opposite of current behaviour -> you have to negate current condition:

```
if (! (strstr($Description1,'word1') or strstr($Description1,'word2') )){ 
do Action 1
} else 
Action 2
```

which, due to [De Morgan's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) will become:

```
if (!strstr($Description1,'word1') and !strstr($Description1,'word2') ){ 
do Action 1
} else 
Action 2
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if (!strstr($Description1,'word1') and !strstr($Description1,'word2') ){ 
do Action 1
} else 
Action 2
```

Answer (score 1):

That's a basic boolean error. You want to make sure that:

- "word1" is **NOT** in the string **AND**
- "word2" is **NOT** in the string.

Try this:

```
if (!strstr($somestring, "word1") && !strstr($somestring, "word2")) {
    // $somestring does not contain "word1" and "word2"
} else {
    // $somestring contains "word1", "word2" or both
}
```

From the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php) though:

> If you only want to determine if a particular needle occurs within haystack, use the faster and less memory intensive function [strpos()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
 if(strpos($Description1, 'word1') !== FALSE || strpos($Description2, 'word2') !== FALSE)     
 {

 } else {

 }
```

Comment: What's going on here?? `!== FALSE` (not equal to false) is just a convoluted way of rewriting the original question code. How did this get upvotes?

Comment: @DainisAbols I'm aware of how to test strpos(), my issue is that the question seemed to want to reverse the conditions, and this code just maintains the same conditions, written in a different style.

Answer (score 0):

Well you could easily swap the code in the else block. That would reverse the condition :)

The better way perhaps would be to negate the actual condition. For this you can add a `!` character to the conditional expression.

```
if ( condition == true ){
  // condition is equal to a "true" value
}

if ( !condition == true ){
  // condition is NOT equal to a "true" value
}
```

The negating `!` pretty much means that what ever boolean result is returned, use the opposite.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this in a `foreach` loop, for better reading and later editing:

```
<?php

$words = array( 'word1', 'word2' );
$Description1 = 'My word1';

$found = 0;
foreach( $words as $word )
    if ( strpos( $Description1, $word ) !== false )
        $found++;

switch ( $found ) {
    case 1:
        // Action
        break;
    case 2:
        // Action
        break;
    default:
        echo $found . ' found.';
        break;
}

?>
```